# PHP upload file fails with 0 length array.

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file using php.  The script works sometimes flawlessly, but other times it does not. When it doesn't work, the $_FILES array is completetly empty (print_r yields Array()). I can't error check because $_FILES["file"]["error"] is empty.  The behaviour is consistent through IE, Chrome, and Firefox.  The file seems to be uploading as the progress bar indicates.

The scipt as it stands returns Invalid file type again because $_FILES is empty.  If I remove the file type check, move_uploaded_file returns false and the script returns my custom "file may have failed" message.  The only errors error_reporting returns are index errors whenever I try and access $_FILES - again because it is empty.

I have seen other questions with file upload issues, but I haven't come across anyone with this specific problem.  I can't think it is a permissions issue, because, as I said the script does work sometimes.  Although I am testing for multiple file types, I have only tried to upload mp3 files.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

print_r($_FILES);

if  (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/x-mp3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
{


    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "\nReturn Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "\nUpload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "\nType: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "\nSize: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "\nTemp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
        $fname = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $put_file = $_POST["put_dir"] . "/" . $fname;
        echo "\nDestination File: " . $put_file . "<br />";

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $put_file))
        {
            echo "The file " .  $fname . " has been uploaded";              

        }
        else
        {
            echo "The file " .  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) . " may have failed";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML form must have enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute, is it?

I think it is can help you: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Yes I do have the form set up that way.  As I said, the script works a lot of the time and is always comeing from the same page / form.  And thanks for the very quick response - I only posted about 10 minutes ago!

Comment: Maybe file is bigger than max_upload_size or max_post_size value in php.ini? Are any errors in error.log?

Comment: Ok it looks like that was it.  Strange how it would not throw an error though.  Thanks for your help.